# Trying to figure what typeface / font this is

Tags: typography, typefaces, style-identification

Here is a character table I hand-assembled from a book that was published in 1954. I'm trying to figure what font this was typeset in. The scan I have is of very low quality but it is good enough to observe the characteristic uppercase 'G', 'J', 'K', 'Q', 'R', and 'W', and the italic lowercase 'p' and uppercase 'W'. The closest font I found so far is Baskerville but it doesn't fit the uppercase and lowercase 'j' plus many other details.

Anyone recognize this font?
[image: Mystery font].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Q is very distinctive: it's Electra by [William Addison Dwiggins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electra_(typeface)#/media/File:Linotype_Electra_Type_Specimen_(34534069663).jpg).

[image: image of Linotype Electra]

If this is the regular weight not the bold, it's very heavily inked on the page. Electra has been digitized a couple of times but I don't know of any digital version this heavy on the page.

Comment: Everything fits exactly including small caps and old style numerals. Thank you very much. Concerning the "heavy inking", at first, I was on the impression that this was an effect of the scanning process (I got the scans from Internet Archive) or the result of applying a mean filter to remove noise, because of the coarse pixellation and the fact that the scans systematically missed thin stems. Anyway, I'm not looking for such heeavy font.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

For me it's hard to recognise font just ny seeing
But don't worry i know a way ,
I'm assuming you have adobe acrobat dc
Save that font as a pdf or any image file
Open it in adobe acrobat
Go to edit option and click on the font
You will see the name of the font in the drop down menu in edit option

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately this doesn't really answer the question. The OP has scanned the text from a book, so it's not a font that can be checked in Acrobat.